# Importing Node Modules in to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, jasmine, bower

I'm working with Jasmine. I spotted this handy looking library: https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers and I thought its collection of customer matchers would help me a lot.

Problem is, it's loaded with files common to Node applications, such as JSHint, Grunt, travis.yml etc

The project I'm working on, that would love these matchers, is a Rails application. I've tried dropping them into my assets/javascripts and requiring in application.js, but obviously, life isn't that simple.

What is the correct way to install these files, and integrate them with Jasmine in a Rails context? Is Bower the tool for the job? If so, what's the right procedure to adding JS dependencies/integrating them off the bat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of Jasmine-Matchers here, the only file you need to load into your test environment is this one https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers/blob/master/dist/jasmine-matchers.js.

The other files are part of the development repo, I'll open an issue to have those excluded from npm/bower packages to save confusion.

You should be able to copy that file to your assets/javascripts directory, then embed it after Jasmine but before your tests.

Please comment if I've missed anything out here.

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to use Node modules inside my Rails application and the easiest way I found to achieve it was through [browserify-rails](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails) gem.

The installation is pretty straightforward, just follow the getting started section and everything should be working. :-)